# Is there an alternative to a switch statement, and how would I organize this?

Tags: switch-statement, code-organization, case-statement

After coding for awhile it has occurred to me that a switch statement might not be the best function to run my code, for example, I cannot simplify the case statements into methods of their own because they would be orphaned cases. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this code and what ways I could do this with.

I have tried writing several if statements however that lead to more chaos and disorder even though I could put everything into their own method.
That lead me to the switch statement however I could not simplify this.

here is a segment of the code. This includes the overarching switch statement and the first case.

while (true) //game loop
        {

```
        if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) { //if player types exit at any time the game quits
            System.exit(0);
        } else { //else the game runs

            map();
            Commands(); //runs the command method
            playerDam(); //runs player damage method

            //Handles the story
            switch (question) //if question is equal to...
            {
                case "1": //introduction
                    System.out.println("Welcome to Archewind" +
                        "\nIf in need of help, press help at any time for list of commands. \nIf you would like to exit type exit at any time." +
                        "\nAre you ready to begin? \n[1]Yes\n[2]No");
                    switch (user = in .next()) //if user types one... if two...
                    {
                        case "1": //this happens
                            System.out.println("\n");
                            System.out.println("Great. Good luck");

                            question = "1.5";
                            gametic = 1;
                            break;

                        case "2": //this happens
                            System.out.println("\n");
                            System.out.println("Oh... well um... I don't really know what to do here. People usually say yes.");
                            System.out.println("\nDo you think you're ready now? \n[1]Yes \n[2]No");

                            switch (user = in .next()) {
                                case "1":
                                    System.out.println("\n");
                                    System.out.println("Ok goood, I was getting worried there for a second. Good luck.");

                                    question = "1.5";
                                    gametic = 1;
                                    break;

                                case "2":
                                    System.out.println("\n");
                                    System.out.println("Really? [1]Yes [2]No");

                                    switch (user = in .next()) {
                                        case "1":
                                            System.out.println("\n");
                                            System.out.println("This is just getting long. Do you know what you're doing to the programmer? He has to code all of this you know" +
                                                "\nIm just going to give you a choice. Either say yes next time or I am going to shut down. I mean it." +
                                                "\nStart game? \n[1]Yes \n[2]No");

                                            switch (user = in .next()) {
                                                case "1":
                                                    System.out.println("\n");
                                                    System.out.println("Alllrriiight.. Lets get this party started.");
                                                    question = "1.5";
                                                    gametic = 1;
                                                    break;


                                                case "2":
                                                    System.out.println("\n");
                                                    System.out.println("Nope. I'm done.");
                                                    user = "exit";
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            case "2":
                                                System.out.println("Ok good. We can finally get this show on the road.");
                                    }
                            }
                            question = "1.5";
                            gametic = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
```

Here is another segment.

case "1.5":

```
                    System.out.println("\nNow, before we start you need to choose a class. Each one will offer diffrent benefits.");
                    int rank = getRank();
                    userClass = RANKS[rank];
                    System.out.println("Your chosen class is: " + userClass);

                    if (userClass.equals("Farmer")) {
                        playerhealth = playerhealth + 1;
                        inv.remove("Health Potion");
                        inv.remove("Water Bottle");
                    }

                    if (userClass.equals("Trader")); {
                        inv.add("Health Potion");
                        inv.remove("Water Bottle");
                        if (playerhealth == 6) {
                            playerhealth = playerhealth - 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (userClass.equals("Wanderer")); {
                        inv.add("Water Bottle");
                        inv.remove("Health Potion");
                        if (playerhealth == 6) {
                            playerhealth = playerhealth - 1;
                        }
                    }

                    gametic = 2;
                    question = "2";
                    break;
```

I expected this to be a lot more simplified than it turned out to be, but I can't seem to break down the case statements into their own methods so everything is a lot more organized.

Answer (score 0):

My approach in this case, is to write a Factory pattern along with Command pattern.
Each "segment" of work to be done can be placed in a class which implements an interface with one important method: execute().
As follows:
The Interface is:

```
public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

All commands would implement it:

```
public class SayWelcomeCommand implements Command {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }
}
```

And another command for "Trader" work:

```
public class TraderCommand implements Command {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // doing some work...
        inv.add("Health Potion");
        inv.remove("Water Bottle");
        // more work...      
    }
}
```

You create commands according to a known string key:

```
public class CommandsFactory {
    public static Command createCommand(String commandKey) {
        switch (commandKey) {
        case 'welcome': return new SayWelcomeCommand(); break;
        case 'trader': return new TraderCommand(); break;
        case 'exit': return new ExitCommand(); break;  // todo: create that cmd..
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your MAIN program, you would simply call the factory and execute!

```
while (true) {
    String commandKey =  System.in.readLine... // get from the user a command.
    Command command = CommandFactory.createCommand(commandKey);
    command.execute();
}
```

This way you keep creating different commands endlessly until the "exit" command simply shutdown the game.. with a message for example.

The switch simply moved to the Factory but even there you could enhance the factory to read by reflection the class names from config file and place them in a map of String to Command objects (The Map key will be a string, the command key.  And the Map value will be the Command object). so you will completely remove the use of switch from your program.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I'm not sure what a factory is, can you explain it a little bit. So if I understand what you're thinking, I create several different 'factories' which hold the code that the switch statement did.

Comment: Usually we create objects using the 'new' keyword. E.g: `Color myFavoriteColor = new Color(127, 45, 87)`.  We can "wrap" the creation of this object by a Factory method that accepts an easier to remember parameter, like a name of the color instead of those 3 numbers of Red,Green,Blue...  so our code would look like this: `Color myFavoriteColor = MyColorFactory.createColor("MyFavorite")` And in the factory method you will use those numbers like this: `public static Color createColor(String colorName) { if (colorName.equals("MyFavorite")) { return new Color(27, 45, 87); } }.`. That is a Factory.